# How to stop application quit or run in background till certain process finishes in iphone sdk?

Tags: iphone, ios, terminate, quit

in my application i am doing some synchronization of data from server.I want to stop quiting of application or running app in background till this process finishes.i.e.once this process is started user can not quit or app should not go in background till this process finishes.is it possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, you cannot prevent the user from quitting the app.

But you can run your sync in the background using e.g. ASIHTTPRequest..